# Update output to unix in realtime

Tags: perl, unix

Im sure this is common but I was having trouble finding anything on google...

I am using Perl and I am running my program in UNIX. At one point in my program I am printing numbers which represent the number of regex matches found. Anyway the output is something like this..

```
1
2
3
4 
5
```

etc..

It ends up being quite a long list, so if you want to get to the top or bottom of the output you have to do a ton of scrolling...

My question is how can I get the list output to update in realtime, so the list output would stay on one line. so that `1` changes to `2` changes to `3` etc..

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just curious: what Unix are you on?

Comment: Use something like the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library. [Curses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses) is one option for using it in Perl.

Comment: Im sorry I am actually on GNU/Linux. Im not sure how to find my version or anything else, but I was hoping there was a general *nix solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget to unbuffer output in your Perl with:

```
$|=1;
```

Then try:

```
$(tput clear);
```

to put cursor to top of terminal window.

Try typing:

```
tput clear
```

into your terminal to see if that clears the screen and puts the cursor at top left. If not, try typing:

```
clear
```

to clear the screen and get cursor to "Home" position.

Comment: Thanks, autoflushing the output was what I needed to do. Though Im not sure how to use `$(tput clear)`. I got it to work by first doing: `local $| = 1;` then using `\r` when `print`ing my output.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on a lot of things, but `\r` in a string should return the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: You'll need to flush your output since there won't be a `\n` to trigger it. `$| = 1;`  will automatically flush STDOUT.